# Entity Framework with sqlserver 2012 arabic data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I had an a .net application that **was working** on **SQL Server 2008 R2**, inside it there a **database** that contains **Arabic** data, the database **collation** is **arabic_cs_ai**, i **upgraded** the **sql server** to **2012 enterprise**, i have an application that use the **entity framework 6.x**, when i'm **getting** data from table person its appearing in **Arabic**, while i'm **saving new data** in the same table, it's **saved** into **sql** as **question marks(?)**, i used the **SQL profiler to monitor** the **query**, the data on **sql profiler** **appeared** as **question marks(?)**.

***Note:*** The server and the application is on a different pc's

Comment: Are your database columns of NVARCHAR type?

Comment: no varchar with collation arabic_cs_ai

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your connection string in App.Config:

```
Charset=utf8&quot;"
```

Comment: its not working, error keyword not supported exception:'charset'

Answer (score 0):

Solved, We had a citirix server net scalar system, it was the problem, we solved it by connecting directly to sql without citrix